# Print page content with formatting when doing custom SQL query

Tags: pages, sql, footer

I guess there's a simple solution for this but couldn't find any.

I'm trying to fetch 3 pages and show them on footer. The problem is that ***every page is shown as text without formatting*** which means that ***shortcodes are printed as text as well***.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
global $wpdb;
$sql            = "SELECT post_title, post_content FROM ...";
$footerElements = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );

foreach ( $footerElements as $footerElement ) {
    echo '<div class="four columns">';
    echo '<h5>' . $footerElement->post_title . '</h5>';
    echo $footerElement->post_content;
    echo '</div>';      
}
```

The reason I'm using `SQL` and not `WP_Query` is I have a plugin with `pre_get_posts` which is explicitly setting `post_types` (excluding `page`) when in category or tag page is shown. So I can't use `WP_Query` for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the `post_content` filters. It is a one line change from your current code.

This...

```
echo $footerElement->post_content;
```

... should be ...

```
echo apply_filters('the_content',$footerElement->post_content);
```

That will give you all the same formatting as with normal posts.

You can of course pick and choose which filters you want to run, instead of running them all, and you may want to do that in case a plugin adds something to the post content via a filter (for example, a G+ button). Take a look at the [default filters](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/default-filters.php) for `the_content` and check the Codex for the functions of the various callbacks.

To elaborate on that last idea, filter callbacks are basically functions that take input and return a (usually) modified version of that input. That means you can pretty much call them directly if you need to. They are functions like any other. For example...

Take this filter from [`default-filters.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/default-filters.php) :

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wptexturize'            );
```

The callback function is [`wptexturize`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wptexturize). If you wanted to run that "filter" and only that filter you could write:

```
echo wptexturize($footerElement->post_content);
```

I can't swear that will work with every filter out there, since sometimes people do oddball things with filters, but it should work with most-- especially the core filters.

Another thing you can do is [remove particular filters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_filter) if you know which ones you don't want to run. It could be easier than typing out the ones you do want to run.

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wptexturize' );
// some code maybe
echo apply_filters('the_content',$footerElement->post_content);
// more code maybe
// add the filter back in case it is used later in the page
add_filter('the_content','wptexturize');
```

Comment: OMG! That was fast, and what's the best... It f'king works! Thank you so much. Been struggling with my footer's WP_Query for 3 days now, until I realised that one plugin was causing pages not showing in the footer when the user is on tag/category page (has pre_get_posts). Appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by `pick and choose which filters you want to run, instead of running them all`... isn't that just picking the `the_content` filter?